# How to test if 2 SKSpriteNodes collide

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Hi I am a newbie in IOS Dev.
I would like to text if my hull node and my fallingObject node collide.
Once it collided, I want to remove that fallingObject node.

In my code I created a basket in my Scene. then on a Random point on the screen it creates a fallingObject node.

My goal is once the fallingObject collides (or catched) by the hull (imaginary box inside the basket node). the fallingObject would disappear or removed from the Scene.

Please see my code below:

```
static const uint32_t boxCategory  = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t fallingObjectCategory = 0x1 << 1;

#import "MyScene.h"

    - (SKSpriteNode *)newBasket
        {
            SKSpriteNode *basketImage = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"basket-01.png"];
            basketImage.size = CGSizeMake(150,120);

            SKSpriteNode *hull = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(64,32)];
            [basketImage addChild:hull];

            hull.alpha = 0.0;
            hull.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:hull.size];
            hull.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;


            hull.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = boxCategory;
            hull.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fallingObjectCategory;
            hull.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = boxCategory | fallingObjectCategory;

            _basket = basketImage;
            _box =hull;

            return basketImage;
        }

        - (void)addFallingObject
        {

            SKSpriteNode *fallingObject = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:[self getRandomFallingObject]];

            //Configure the Size
            switch (randomNumber) {
                case 0:
                    fallingObject.size = CGSizeMake(70,45);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fallingObject.size = CGSizeMake(30,45);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fallingObject.size = CGSizeMake(40,90);
                    break;
                default:
                    fallingObject.size = CGSizeMake(50,50);
                    break;
            }


            fallingObject.position = CGPointMake(skRand(0, self.size.width), self.size.height-50);
            fallingObject.name = @"fallingObject";
            fallingObject.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:fallingObject.size];
            self.physicsWorld.speed = 0.30;

           fallingObject.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fallingObjectCategory;
           fallingObject.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = boxCategory;
           fallingObject.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = fallingObjectCategory | boxCategory;

            [self addChild:fallingObject];

        }

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    NSLog(@"contact detected");

    SKPhysicsBody *boxBody;
    SKPhysicsBody *fallingObjectBody;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        boxBody = contact.bodyA;
        fallingObjectBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        boxBody = contact.bodyB;
        fallingObjectBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if ((boxBody.categoryBitMask & boxCategory) !=0 && (fallingObjectBody.categoryBitMask & fallingObjectCategory) !=0)
    {
        //do whatever you want like remove a node
    }

}
```

thank you for all your help. :D

Comment: You may want to look into the didBeginContact method in Sprite Kit.  This checks for contact, then you can do whatever you want.  To remove the node just use removeFromParent.

Comment: I have this code: -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    NSLog(@"There is a Collision here!"); 
}

Comment: but NSLog is still not showing even there is collision.

Comment: Have you set the collision masks?  Each node needs a mask.

Comment: i have added masks. Please check edited code. thank you @Douglas for patience. im an amateur.

Comment: I believe they need to be different numbers so you can check in the didBeginContact method.

Comment: Also, you need to make their physicsBody.dynamic = YES.

Comment: Response to being an amateur.  Aren't we all!!!  Not a problem love to help out.

Comment: Just a note, I used a tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's site to make this code.  He has some great tuts on sprite kit and they are free!

Comment: let me check on that. thanks for your help. btw, I used the SpriteKit tut on developer.apple

Comment: Just had an idea that I put in a comment.  Did you make the .h the Physics Contact Delegate?

Comment: Let me know if you get this working, I am dying to find out what you did!

Comment: im studying the tutorial you said and will integrate my code from there..

Answer (score 1):

I have a sprite kit game with two things that collide.  One is the player and one is the charge.  I set up a category for both like this before all my code.  This is before all my imports and stuff.

```
static const uint32_t playerCategory  = 0x1 << 4;
static const uint32_t chargeCategory = 0x1 << 5;
```

Then when I make each node I use the following.

```
self.player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
self.player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = chargeCategory;
self.player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = chargeCategory | selfCategory;
```

and for the charge.

```
_chargedBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = chargeCategory; 
_chargedBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory | selfCategory | chargeCategory;
```

This tells the player it can collide with a charge and something I called self, but that is not necessary right now.

Then in didBeginContact I use.

```
SKPhysicsBody *playerBody, *chargeBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    playerBody = contact.bodyA;
    chargeBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    playerBody = contact.bodyB;
    chargeBody = contact.bodyA;
}

if ((playerBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) !=0 && (chargeBody.categoryBitMask & chargeCategory) !=0)
{  
  //do whatever you want like remove a node
}
```

EDIT #1

I actually make my objects in initWithSize.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
{   // a bunch of code

    self.player = [[Player alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"character"];
    self.player.name = @"MyPlayer";
    self.player.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0f, 120);
    self.player.zPosition = 15;
    self.player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.player.frame.size];
    self.player.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    self.player.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    self.player.physicsBody.mass = 0.25;
    self.player.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    self.player.physicsBody.friction = 0.5;
    self.player.physicsBody.restitution = 0.3;
    self.player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    self.player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = chargeCategory;
    self.player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = chargeCategory | selfCategory;
    [self.map addChild:self.player];

 }
```

Then I make the other obj in a method.

```
- (void)spawnChargesWithNumber:(int)number
{   // some code
 _chargedBall.position = (CGPointMake(_randomX, random));
_chargedBall.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chargeNumber%i", number];
_chargedBall.zPosition = 15;
_chargedBall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:13.0f];
_chargedBall.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.mass = 0.1;
_chargedBall.velocity = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0); //changed actualVelocityX to 0
_chargedBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = chargeCategory;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory | selfCategory | chargeCategory;
[self.map addChild:_chargedBall];
```

}

EDIT #2
This might clear some things up.  It is from the Apple Docs.

***categoryBitMask

A mask that defines which categories this physics body belongs to.

@property(assign, nonatomic) uint32_t categoryBitMask
Discussion
Every physics body in a scene can be assigned to up to 32 different categories, each corresponding to a bit in the bit mask. You define the mask values used in your game. In conjunction with the collisionBitMask and contactTestBitMask properties, you define which physics bodies interact with each other and when your game is notified of these interactions.

The default value is 0xFFFFFFFF (all bits set).

Availability
Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
See Also
  @property collisionBitMask
  @property contactTestBitMask
Declared In
SKPhysicsBody.h

***collisionBitMask

A mask that defines which categories of physics bodies can collide with this physics body.

@property(assign, nonatomic) uint32_t collisionBitMask
Discussion
When two physics bodies contact each other, a collision may occur. This body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category mask by performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a non-zero value, then this body is affected by the collision. Each body independently chooses whether it wants to be affected by the other body. For example, you might use this to avoid collision calculations that would make negligible changes to a body’s velocity.

The default value is 0xFFFFFFFF (all bits set).

Availability
Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
See Also
  @property categoryBitMask
Declared In
SKPhysicsBody.h

***contactTestBitMask

A mask that defines which categories of bodies cause intersection notifications with this physics body.

@property(assign, nonatomic) uint32_t contactTestBitMask
Discussion
When two bodies share the same space, each body’s category mask is tested against the other body’s contact mask by performing a logical AND operation. If either comparison results in a non-zero value, an SKPhysicsContact object is created and passed to the physics world’s delegate. For best performance, only set bits in the contacts mask for interactions you are interested in.

The default value is 0x00000000 (all bits cleared).

Availability
Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
See Also
  @property categoryBitMask
Declared In
SKPhysicsBody.h

Comment: what do  0x1 << 4 this mean? because I added the codes as you instructed but still my NSLog is not working.. :(

Comment: If you only want the falling object to interact with the hull object change the collision bit mask.  For the falling obj just use hull and for the hull just use falling obj.  And don't forget to make the physicsBody.dynamic = YES.  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: is this what you mean?  hull.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = fallingObjectCategory;  fallingObject.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = boxCategory; Its not colliding anymore.. @Douglas

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, but they should collide still.  Is the physicsBody.dynamic = YES ?  And make sure the zPosition is the same.

Comment: Yes I have hull.physicsBody =  YES; and fallingObject.physicsBody = YES; both hull and fallingObject has .zPosition = 1; still not colliding..

Comment: Try this, because my sprites are a bit different then yours, comment out the contactBitMask and see if they collide now.  Keep the collisionBitMask the same.

Comment: it collides if I set following: hull.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;hull.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = boxCategory; hull.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = boxCategory|fallingObjectCategory; and NO zPosition. But still the problem is it does not enter this method: -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact

Comment: Very interesting.  Did you make sure that you set in your .h file the SKPhysicsContactDelegate? Right after the @interface MyScene:SKScene put a <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>  If that doesn't work I am not sure what is going on.  Try the tutorial at Ray Wenderlich, search for the sprite kit tuts.  Maybe that will shed some light on the problem.  The code works for me, but again I am making my sprites a bit differently than you.